# Allign lettrine with title

Tags: vertical-alignment, koma-script, titlesec, lettrine

I would like to recreate the look of the first page of an old book. Is it possible to align the initial with the section title?

[image]

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{microtype,fontspec,lettrine}    
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\scshape\LARGE\raggedleft}{}{0pt}{#1\quad\thesection}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}
\lettrine[loversize=0.9, lines=3]{S}{ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque} laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don't load `titlesec` with `scrbook`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not combine `titlesec` with KOMA-Script classes. So I've first changed your basic section formatting using the KOMA-Script user interfaces, in this case `\setkomafont` to change the font of sections and redefinition of `\secionlinesformat` to change the order of section number and section title. To remove the dot after the section number you can either use class option `numbers=noenddot` or redefine `\sectionformat`. To print the section heading right aligned, you can either change `\raggedsection` to change the alignment of *all* levels, or add a `\raggedleft` to the definition of `\sectionlinesformat`. IMHO printing all section, subsection etc. headings with the same alignment makes more sense, so I'll use a redefinition of `\raggedsection`.

Than you can use `\RedeclareSectionCommand` to change the vertical spacing of section commands.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{microtype,fontspec,lettrine}    
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}
\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{\thesection}% no dot or space behind the number
\let\raggedsection\raggedleft
\setkomafont{section}{\normalfont\Large\scshape}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
  \Ifstr{#1}{section}
    {#4\quad#3}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
  }
\makeatother
\RedeclareSectionCommand[afterskip=-\ht\strutbox,runin=false]{section}% change space after heading

\begin{document}
\section{Hello world}
\lettrine[loversize=0.9, lines=3]{S}{ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque} laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi...
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notes:

- The value `-\ht\strutbox` is estimated. If this is not enough, you can also use absolute values like `-1.5ex` or `-10pt`. But don't forget to use `runin=false`. Otherwise you'd define a runin heading because of the negative `afterskip`. See the KOMA-Script manual for more information.
- If there are multi-line section headings, a definition like

  ```
  \renewcommand*{\sectionlinesformat}[4]{%
    \Ifstr{#1}{section}
      {\parbox[b]{.8\textwidth}{\raggedleft #4}\quad#3}
      {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}%
  }
  ```

  could be useful. But in this case you'd first have to decide, how to print long section headings.
- I've uses `scrartcl`, because IMHO it does not make sense to use `scrreprt` if you don't use `\chapter`. However, the solution would also work with `scrreprt`.
- In addition to the KOMA-Script manuals, there is also a [section about formatting of section headings in the KOMA-Script wiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-en/HowTo_Headings/), with several examples about usage of the commands also used in this answer. The wiki is also [available in German](https://sourceforge.net/p/koma-script/wiki-de/HowTo_Headings/).

Answer (score 0):

Since `titlesec` is not compatible with `scrbook`, I'll use `book`.

An approximate measuring gave about 22pt, with a bit of visual formatting it has to be reduced to 21pt.

I'll leave a bit of overshoot.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{
  microtype,
  fontspec,
  lettrine
}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}[block]
  {\scshape\LARGE\raggedleft}
  {}
  {0pt}
  {#1\quad\thesection}
\titlespacing*{\section}
 {0pt}
 {3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}
 {-21pt}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\Roman{section}}

\begin{document}

\section{Hello world\makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule height \dimeval{\fontcharht\font`H+0.2pt}
depth -\fontcharht\font`H width \textwidth}}

\lettrine[loversize=0.9,lines=3]{S}{ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  
iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque} laudantium, 
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et 
quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam 
voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia 
consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi...

\section{Hello world\makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule height \dimeval{\fontcharht\font`H+0.2pt}
depth -\fontcharht\font`H width \textwidth}}

\lettrine[loversize=0.9,lines=3]{T}{ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  
iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque} laudantium, 
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et 
quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam 
voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia 
consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi...

\section{Hello world\makebox[0pt][r]{\vrule height \dimeval{\fontcharht\font`H+0.2pt}
depth -\fontcharht\font`H width \textwidth}}

\lettrine[loversize=0.9,lines=3]{B}{ed ut perspiciatis unde omnis  
iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque} laudantium, 
totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et 
quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam 
voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia 
consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi...

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did you calculate 22pt?

Comment: I would like to remove titlesec, but I don't know how to display the section number after its name.